# Number of routes in a camel bundle

Tags: apache-camel

We have a lot of routes in a camel bundle. And we want to add few more. 
Do we have a limit on the number routes we can have in a bundle?
Is there a performance bottleneck directly proportional to the the number of routes we have in a bundle?

Comment: No you can has as many as you want, the performance is impacted on what the routes are doing.

Comment: thanks, Claus Ibsen. Do we have any common performance issues with a set of routes(components) working together in a single bundle.. like don't put too much of these components together in a single bundle... that sort of standard designs to improve the overall performance of a bundle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Claus mentioned, there is no limit to the number of routes
2. I would add to Claus's performance answer that the number of threads starts to become an issue when you get to the 100's-1000's of routes.

To optimize at that scale, leverage shared logic in routes where possible (direct, direct-vm, seda, vm:// endpoints).

Also, many routes that start with a http-listener can be consolidated to a single route that listens to all endpoints, then does a CBR/dynamic router to various sub-route handlers. This helps cut down significantly on the number of threads and thread pools running around that get started by listener Camel components.

Similar approach applies for other transport technologies.